# 1998 Mercedes ML320 - Too many keys?

Tags: mercedes-benz, key, intermittent-problems

I recently bought a Mercedes it only had one key I went to order another key and the dealer told me six have already been made I cannot make an additional key sounds crazy but what would I do to have a second key? Does anybody know

Comment: Adding this as a comment since I'm not totally sure, but on other cars that have that sort of security changing the security/ignition module should do the trick since that's where the key codes are held. Naturally this is something the dealer would have to do and it's probably not cheap. I would give them a call back and see what your options are. If they can't give you any, call another dealer.

Comment: You should be able to purchase a second key (for you), but you need to make sure that your two keys are "paired" to the vehicle and this will also remove the older keys so they should no longer work with your vehicle to prevent a security or theft issue.